# How can I install a plugin on a Wordpress.com hosted blog?

Tags: plugins, wordpress.com-hosting

I used to have a self hosted wordpress blog but I switch to a wordpress.com one. I can't seem to find the plugins area.

Any help?

Comment: @Serg - Get yourself a self-hosting WordPress blog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You [can't upload plugins on WordPress.com](http://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/). For security and performance reasons, you can only run what wordpress.com staff has approved.

Answer (score 0):

They're saying:

"If there is a plugin that you feel is a must-have and would benefit users on WordPress.com, then please let us know using our contact form! Tell us what plugin you want, where it can be downloaded and most importantly, why you think it should be included on WordPress.com."

Any luck on that?

I just wanted to have flash content on my blog as I'm a photographer and I want to have my pictures in flash.

I'm planning to upgrade and pay for my own domain via wordpress.com but now I'm hesitant without the ability to get flash albums.