# How to install a plugin for a free WordPress site?

Tags: plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install a plugin on a Wordpress.com hosted blog?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3727/how-can-i-install-a-plugin-on-a-wordpress-com-hosted-blog)

I've a free WordPress (xxx.wordpress.com) blog and now I want to install a plugin like the way I install them with my WordPress site at my own domain. Can't find it in the menu. Isn't this possible with a free WordPress site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't add plugin's to WordPress.com the Free websites. They can't allow free sites to add possible vulnerable plug-ins to the server. This would drive up the costs and make it impossible to offer them for free.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds reasonable. But how can I for example use SEO settings like the ones possible with the All in One SEO Pack?

Comment: The best you can do is use relevant content in your posts. If you want the plugin options consider a self hosted website. You can get a domain name for $20.00 a year, and hosting from 5-15 dollars a month.

Comment: Yes I know, I own another WordPress blog (own domain), but I was trying a second (free) one, just to investigate the possibilities. But I think a free site is a poor alternative, for what I've seen now, at least for me. Thanks anyway

Comment: Upload WordPress to a sub-directory and add a Database for it.

Answer (score 4):

The most simple answer is, no. Unfortunately not. Unless you are part of The [VIP program on WordPress.com](http://vip.wordpress.com/) for high-traffic and high-profile sites which allows you to run custom themes, custom PHP code, ad code, and WordPress plugins.

Source: http://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/